# I take a piece of 2D space and draw a (or any) curve on it. What are the assumptions I need to identify this curve to an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

The physical analogue would be taking a piece of paper and drawing a curve on it.

If I'm able to identify the curve to an equation, I would be able to perform algebra on that equation in such a way that the result would be another curve that would lie on the plane, or I could perform an algebraic operation on the equation such that it could no longer represent any curve. I'm thinking of for example the way we define vector spaces to make vectors behave in the way we expect them to. What are the assumptions behind for instance having $ax + by + c = 0$ be able to be plotted as a continuous line on the Cartesian plane, or any other curve?

---

A bit of an explanation of the question:

The idea stems from a comparison between an Euclidean plane (i.e. the one where Euclid does his proofs) and a Cartesian one. So as to produce some sort of correspondence between these two planes, surely we have to assume a certain structure on the Cartesian plane, so that results in one can apply to the other, but so that in the Cartesian plane we can draw geometrical figures in terms of equations.

This wouldn't be a problem if geometrical figures on the Cartesian plane could be dealt with so that there is a 1 to 1 correspondence in the algebra with the length of a segment, or e.g. $x^2$ and the area of a square, as for instance in the proofs of Book 2 of Euclid, where we could really speak of a sort of geometrical algebra. Somewhere in our transition between the Euclidean plane and the Cartesian one, we lose a lot of information to be able to use equations to model curves, and get unintuitive results like the equation of a line $ax + by + c = 0$, which I can't bring myself to believe unless I plot the points which satisfy the equation, or otherwise change its form.

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the Cartesian plane, and the equation of common geometrical forms like $ax + by + c = 0$ or $x^3 + y^3 = 0$ for a line, or $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ for a circle, which seem to be very far away from the notion of an algebra where $x$ would correspond to a line, $x^2$ to a square and $x^3$ to a cube.

In a limited sense, e.g., $ax + by + c = 0$ does behave like a line would insofar as if I increase $a$, I get a rotation, if I increase $b$, I get a rotation, and if I increase $c$, I get a translation, but this seems completely coincidental to me, and it feels like any such properties of equations modeling curves are *a posteriori*, as in impossible to discover unless you actually perform the modification and then plot anew.

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ is almost intuitive if we imagine a right triangle with hypotenuse of length $r$ in it, but then if we make a translation, the equation ceases to make any sense to me, especially if we distribute: $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2 \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ x^2 - 2xh + h^2 + y^2 - 2yk + k^2 = r^2$.

I'm supposing that by making explicit the structure we assume about the Cartesian plane (or other planes where we could plot a curve) I could get a deeper insight into the form these equations take.

References would be very welcome.

Comment: In what sense do we loose information when using cartesian coordinates? If I recall correctly $\Bbb R^2$ satisfies the axioms of an euclidean plane and the euclidean plane is uniquely determined (via isometric isomorphism or something like that). With other words we have *gained* the information that we can use coordinates to study the euclidean plane. Sure we need to choose an origin and two directions $e_x$ and $e_y$ to use the coordinates, but this is not really a restriction, since we can study affine geometry (in the sense of working with tuples $(o,V)$, where $o$ is some point of the ...

Comment: ... plane and $V$ is the vector space spanned by some directions. This would explain, why the pythagorean theorem behaves *weird* regarding translation. Distances with respect to coordinates are measured from the chosen origin. In the case of pythagoras this means that one of the vertices of the triangle is the origin. However the transformation you gave did not move the origin but the other two vertices, resulting in a completely new triangle, which will certainly not have the same hypothenuse of length $r$.

Comment: @PrudiiArca  on losing information:  while in euclidean geometry we can immediately see the objects and the theorems, and that here an equation x^2 = ab means that a square on a segment of length x equals a rectangle contained by a and b, the curve is mediated by an equation in the case of the cartesian plane, where we don't even have a guarantee that there is a relationship between geometry and our equation. We can have an equation that just draws a straight line and we wouldn't be able to recognize it without actually plotting the coordinate pairs satisfying the equation.

Comment: -concerning the circle: the translated circle no longer sticks to the origin, so the circle still has a radius $r$, but the triangle at origin doesn't. We can still draw the pythagorean triangle at $(h, k)$ with radius $r$, but it is no longer clear how the equation forms a circle on the basis of a pythagorean triangle.